# Finding index of a stack java

Tags: java, stack

Trying to find the index with the last element inputted as 0 using stack, I'm using the method pop(), and peek().

Here is my code:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack<String> a = new Stack<>();

        a.push("a");
        a.push("b");
        a.push("c");
        a.push("d");
        a.push("e");
        a.push("f");

        System.out.println(a);
        String str = "f";
        int b = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
            if (a.peek().equalsIgnoreCase(str)){
                break;
            }
            a.pop();
            b++;
        }
        System.out.println(str);
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

Expected output if str = "f":

```
0
```

and yes, when I tried using my solution it works properly.

Until I tried using str = "b"
Expected output:

```
[a, b, c, d, e, f]
b
4
```

Actual output:

```
[a, b, c, d, e, f]
b
3
```

Also using str = "a",
Expected output:

```
[a, b, c, d, e, f]
a
5
```

Actual output:

```
[a, b, c, d, e, f]
a
3
```

So for whatever reason until the last two elements on the stack, int b didn't get incremented. Any idea on why this happens?

Comment: why bother peeking if you are going to pop anyway?

Comment: because for whatever reason inside a loop if you keep peeking, it doesn't move onto the previous element, so you have to keep popping so that you can peek the previous element. atleast thats what happened when i tried it, unless i did something wrong

Comment: @ScaryWombat asked why *peek.* You have to pop, but pop returns the same value as peek, so you don't need the peek. The problem here is that you are incrementing `b` from zero where you should be decrementing it from `a.size()-1`. But what use the index of something in a stack is remains a mystery, and it is even more of a mystery what use it is when the stack has been modified. Actually you don't need `b` at all, as the answer is always `a.size()-1`.

Comment: @user207421 "But what use the index of something in a stack is remains a mystery" true, it's just that my teacher gave students a spesific task, and that task spesifically ordered us to use stack. If it's using any other method of storing elements. I would rather much use that instead. It's just working around the stack itself is pretty confusing to me

Comment: You could always ask your teacher WTH he is talking about. Show him this page. Stacks are accessed via push and pop only, not via indexes: otherwise they cease to be stacks and become mere arrays or lists.

Comment: fax, will gettem next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler way would be to test for `empty`

If not `empty` then `pop`  Pop returns to top object, so you can then test it.  If it matches then break.

Comment: oh wow, thanks it finally worked!

Answer (score 0):

`a.pop()` will change `a.size()`. You should store `a.size()` as length at first and begin the loop to find an index. Finally, if the index of the first inputted element is `0`, then the index of the element you find is `length - b`.